# Copy value from previous line using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

Any ideas how to write a awk/sed script to replace a particular sentinel value or pattern (in this case `PREV` from a value in a different column from the previous line?)

e.g. replace all `PREVs` from the value from first column of the previous line

```
a -> b
c -> PREV
d -> PREV
```

to:

```
a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
```

Comment: Yes. Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried and tell us where you need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$3=p} {p=$1} 1' file
a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
```

Comment: could someone explain please? what does p refer to and whats the purpose of 1 at the end of the command? thanks

Comment: @alphaGeek `p` is a variable, stands for *previous*. `1` means *print every line*

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
a -> b
c -> PREV
d -> PREV
e -> f     # watch this record
g -> PREV
```

To *replace all `PREV`s from the value from first column of the previous line* using awk:

```
$ awk '$3=="PREV"{$3=prev}{prev=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
e -> f     # watch this record
g -> e
```

Answer (score 1):

Golf'd:

```
$ awk '$3=p?p:$3; {p=$1}' file

a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
```

to account for `$1==0`:

```
$ awk '$3 = length(p)? p: $3; {p=$1}' <<EOF
a -> b
c -> PREV
d -> PREV
0 -> PREV
e -> PREV
f -> PREV
EOF

a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
0 -> d
f -> e
```

Comment: assigning $3 is good idea though, i adapted it to my answer, is it ok or should I add a note about it?

Comment: do as you please in this wasteland

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E '/PREV/{G;s/PREV(.*)\n(\S+).*/\2\1/};h' infile
```

Explained:

```
/PREV/ {                       # if the current line matches PREV
    G                          # append hold space to pattern space
    s/PREV(.*)\n(\S+).*/\2\1/  # replace PREV with first word from appended line,
                               # drop newline and rest of appended line
}
h                              # store pattern space in hold space
```

Or, with slight modifications for portability:

```
sed '/PREV/{G;s/PREV\(.*\)\n\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\).*/\2\1/;};h' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -Ez ':s s/((\S+)\s*->[^\n]+\n[^\n]*)PREV\s*/\1\2\n/;ts' d
```

Answer (score 0):

For this content

```
$ cat file
a -> b
c -> PREV
d -> PREV
e -> PREV
g -> GOLD
p -> m
```

Ensure that only PREV sentinel are replaced(others left as it is):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && /PREV/{$3=p}{p=$1} 1' file
a -> b
c -> a
d -> c
e -> d
g -> GOLD
p -> m
```